# how to run android service even app is closed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've created a simple app that save the location of the user using GPS using Xamarin. This is what already doing.

1. When user is using app. The save location is ok.
2. When user minimize the app. The save location is ok.

But when the user closed the app. The save location is not ok. First is that I used **IntentService** but still not working so I tried **Service**.

Below is my code snippet.

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class MyAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        var serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MyReverseGeoCodeLocationService));
        serviceIntent.PutExtras(intent);
        context.StartService(serviceIntent);

    }
}
```

**Service**

```
[Service]
class MyReverseGeoCodeLocationService : Android.App.Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
        {
            CurrentLocationService obj = new CurrentLocationService(new MyLocalStorageService(), this.ApplicationContext);
            obj.OnTimedEvent();

        }).Start();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
var alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyAlarmReceiver));
var pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);


var alarmManager = GetSystemService(AlarmService).JavaCast<AlarmManager>();
alarmManager.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime(), 120000, pending);
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android)

Comment: @Sniffer I think the sample on that website is pretty much the same with mine. It just I used AlarmManager instead of Timer.

Comment: I'm trying to convert this to C# but I don't know how.         timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("in timer", "in timer ++++  "+ (counter++));
            }
        };

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alarms in android.
Look at this page:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms